# Is there a command-line filter tool to condense logs with repetitive entries?

Tags: logging, embedded-linux, syslog, tcpdump, can-bus

Log files often contain repetitive entries, especially in embedded applications. These can make up the vast majority of a log stream or file. The time-sequence format results in large files and makes it difficult to identify outliers and meaningful changes over a longer timescale. It doesn't always make sense to transfer full-format logs from embedded devices to cloud applications for analysis.

I'm looking for a generic command-line filter tool or tools to condense time-sequence log text by removing only redundant entries, that can accept both streaming and static file input, and that can run on an embedded Linux device and laptop. I have not yet found something like this and would like to know if it exists.

Non-repeated content is just passed through.

Repeated content is condensed, such that most or all intermediate instances between the first and last instance of a periodic sequence are excluded.

Instead of redundant output, the filter will output:

- First instance
- (optionally) Additional instances until the sequence has qualified as a repetition
- A designation that the content has been begun to repeat
- Last instance
- Statistics on interval time (min, max, mode, standard deviation)
- Statistics on missing entries (count, percentage)

The tool should have some configurable parameters, such as:

- Read timestamp from text vs use system time of input
- Format of timestamp
- Maximum interval time to qualify as a periodic sequence
- Maximum absolute and/or relative jitter to qualify as a periodic sequence
- Minimum number of repetitions to qualify as a periodic sequence
- Whether repetitive entries are suppressed or delayed when they have not yet been qualified as part of a periodic sequence
- Whether and how often to report statistics during a continuing sequence
- Maximum number of missing repetitions before reporting as a completed sequence

The tool will be useful for repetitive logs and text output such as from syslog, journalctl, candump, tcpdump, etc.

I've started working on such a tool, but would like to know if something already exists that I could borrow from and contribute to. While preparing this question, I looked through 50+ log management tools and didn't find this capability. [The Log File Navigator](http://lnav.org/) looks the closest to being useful and may be a good starting point.

Comment: I think `journalctl` as a part of `systemd` does filtering very well.

Comment: Hi @0andriy, can you explain how to do such content-lossless filtering using journalctl? I have only found with journalctl filtering methods that remove messages, and not methods that summarize their pattern of recurrence.

Comment: I am also looking into this. It seems like no one answered, which means that nothing exists yet?

Comment: @JeffreyUrban What is your progress of that tool?

Comment: @GordonLiang I created company-internal tools spanning most of these capabilities, but was not supported in open-sourcing them.

Comment: I have not yet found other tools with these capabilities.